# How to combine 'onchange' and 'blur' HTML DOM events

Tags: javascript, html, dom, dom-events

Let `MyFunction()` be some JavaScript function. Is it possible to combine the 'onblur' and 'onchange' HTML DOM events (preferably using vanilla Javascript) so that `MyFunction()` is invoked exactly when both events have been triggered (one right after the other)? For example, if I have a HTML5 date field, I would like 'MyFunction()' to be invoked when

1. The date field has been altered AND
2. The date field loses focus after having been altered.

My non-working code piece would like this:

```
<input type="date" 'onchange onblur'="MyFunction()">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution 1:**
Declare global variable that tracks if the date has changed and then reset it on blur.

```
var dateValueChanged = false;

function onChange(){
  dateValueChanged = true;
}

function onBlur(){
  if(dateValueChanged){
    //do thing
    alert('value has changed and blur');
    dateValueChanged = false;
  }
}
```

And the HTML:

```
<input type="date" onchange="onChange()" onblur="onBlur()">
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/xPlZ6GoSOE7wo5VrXJYz?p=preview

**Solution 2**: Pass in the element to onchange and modify the onblur of the element within the onchange function

```
function onChange(el){
  el.setAttribute("onblur", "onBlur(this)");
}

function onBlur(el){
  //do thing
  alert('value has changed and blur');
  el.setAttribute("onblur", "");
}
```

HTML

```
<input type="date" onchange="onChange(this)">
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/PYQ2qITv4SZvh80cCQSM?p=preview

Comment: I got it to work in Safari, but not Chrome (when applied using plnkr.co). In the morning, I will have to investigate if it works for my purpose. Thanks for your suggestion!

Comment: But I am not a fan of the 'dateValueChanged' variable being global.

Comment: Nice, will try it in the morning!

Comment: I went with your second solution, and it worked perfectly. Thx!

Comment: Awesome, glad to help!